# ES6 GroupBy 2 or more

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an ES6 code that works like an SQL Group By.

Here, it groups the items having the same material_no and Sums the qty.

```js
let data = [
  { material_no: '1001', material_name: 'Material 1', qty: 100, date: 'jan' },
  { material_no: '1001', material_name: 'Material 1', qty: 50, date: 'feb' },
  { material_no: '1002', material_name: 'Material 2', qty: 44, date: 'mar' },
  { material_no: '1003', material_name: 'Material 3', qty: 125, date: 'apr' },
  { material_no: '1002', material_name: 'Material 2', qty: 59, date: 'mar' },
  { material_no: '1004', material_name: 'Material 4', qty: 999, date: 'may' },
  { material_no: '1005', material_name: 'Material 5', qty: 80, date: 'jun' },
  { material_no: '1005', material_name: 'Material 5', qty: 66, date: 'jun' }
]

const sums = [
  ...data.reduce(
    (map, item) => {
      const { material_no: key, qty } = item;
      const prev = map.get(key);
      
      if(prev) {
        prev.qty += qty
      } else {
        map.set(key, Object.assign({}, item))
      }
      
      return map
    },
    new Map()
  ).values()
]

console.log(sums)
```

Supposedly, I need to add the 'date' to the Group By logic,

I can't seem to figure out what shall I do, since the code only compares using the material_no as key in the `map.get(key)`. How do I use both material_no and date.

Comment: Concatenate them to form a new key and add a separator if you want (for readability). Like `material_no+'-'+date`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? qty should be summed for items that have the same material_no AND date?

Comment: Can you please add what output exactly you are looking for from the given input `data`.  Also little explanation on how the logic should be?

Comment: Not being picky, but I guess this: `[
  ...data.reduce` is a bad practice.

Comment: qty should be summed, but the group by should be material_no AND date.  IN SQL this should be the statement: "SELECT material_no, material_name, date, SUM(QTY) FROM data GROUP BY material_no, date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a string key which is the concatenation of the `material_no` and and `date`.

```
const { material_no, date, qty } = item;
const key = `${material_no}:${date}`;
```

Comment: I didn't expect this to be this easy. I thought I had to use the && operator or some other things.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [
  { material_no: '1001', material_name: 'Material 1', qty: 100, date: 'jan' },
  { material_no: '1001', material_name: 'Material 1', qty: 50, date: 'feb' },
  { material_no: '1002', material_name: 'Material 2', qty: 44, date: 'mar' },
  { material_no: '1003', material_name: 'Material 3', qty: 125, date: 'apr' },
  { material_no: '1002', material_name: 'Material 2', qty: 59, date: 'mar' },
  { material_no: '1004', material_name: 'Material 4', qty: 999, date: 'may' },
  { material_no: '1005', material_name: 'Material 5', qty: 80, date: 'jun' },
  { material_no: '1005', material_name: 'Material 5', qty: 66, date: 'jun' }
];


var map = {};

data.filter(function(item) {
  if(map[item.material_no + "__" + item.date]) {
    map[item.material_no + "__" + item.date]["qty"] += item.qty;
  } else {
    map[item.material_no + "__" + item.date] = {
      material_name: item.material_name,
      qty: item.qty,
      material_no: item.material_no,
      date: item.date
    };
  }
});


console.log(Object.values(map));
```